# How does ssh login work with KDC client and server?

Tags: kerberos

I would like to get some help to clear my thoughts for kerberos authentiction. I am confused with kerberos authentication flow.

I have three node in my system.

1. (PS) Physical server (neither *krb5-workstation* nor *krb5-lib* are installed)
2. (KC) KDC client (configured with [this](http://red.ht/2wwH2tp))
3. (KS) KDC server (configured with [this](http://red.ht/2v47A4U))

On *KC* , I have *GSSAPIAuthentication* enabled for *sshd*.

```
# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

However, I was expecting to login from *PS* to *KC* via ssh without any password prompt but  instead ,  I get below error on *PS*.

```
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000)
```

My question is ,

Am I missing a configuration or kerberos authentication is *not* available for non-KDC client (*PS*)?

Answer (score 0):

The client ssh user must have a valid credential cache in order to use GSSAPIAuthentication. This is either done as part of the login process, `pam_krb5` / `pam_sss` (`auth_provider = krb5`), or by `kinit` (part of krb5-workstation).

Some minimal configuration is usually necessary, if only to tell a kerberos client to use DNS to locate KDCs and domain_realm mappings.

Comment: What kind of minimal configuration is necessary?